# Cannot install Gnu/Octave on Termux

Tags: android, terminal, octave, executable, termux

I would like to run Gnu/Octave on my Android phone. I have found [this official page](https://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Android), that should be up to date, suggesting the following installation procedure on Termux:

```
pkg install wget
wget https://its-pointless.github.io/setup-pointless-repo.sh
sh setup-pointless-repo.sh
pkg install octave
```

I have followed this procedure, and indeed Octave installed just fine apparently, but then when I tried running `octave` on the terminal to open it for the first time it reported the following error:

```
CANNOT LINK EXECUTABLE: "octave": library "libandroid-support.so" not found
```

I haven't been able to come up with a solution, and I am not sure on why I am getting this error message; I have a pretty recent install of termux, I took it from FDroid a couple of months ago..

What is going on? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I got it running by creating ~/.bashrc and adding

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="${PREFIX}/lib/"

and then starting a new session

got some fatal segmentation fault errors though ...